# Is it true that $E_i = \bigcap_{j=1}^{i-1} \overline{E_j}\cap E_i$?

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

IN some article I'm reading the author has written the following series of inequalities\equalities :

denote by $A_{i}$ and $B_{i}$ the events $\left\{X_{i}^{s}>n^{1 / r} \epsilon\right\}$ and $\left\{\sum_{j=1, j \neq i}^{n} X_{j}^{s}>0\right\}$ respectively, $i=1,2,3, \ldots, n$.

If $\bar{E}$ is the complement of $E$, we then have
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Pr}\left(S_{n}^{s}>n^{\mathrm{1} / r} \epsilon\right) &\geqslant \operatorname{Pr}\left[\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\left(A_{i} \cap B_{i}\right)\right] \\
&=\operatorname{Pr}\left[\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\left\{\bigcap_{j=1}^{i-1} \overline{\left(A_{j} \cap B_{j}\right)} \cap\left(A_{i} \cap B_{i}\right)\right\}\right] \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \operatorname{Pr}\left[\bigcap_{j=1}^{i-1} \overline{\left(A_{j} \cap B_{j}\right)} \cap\left(A_{i} \cap B_{i}\right)\right]
\geqslant \sum_{i=1}^{n} \operatorname{Pr}\left[\bigcap_{j=1}^{i-1} \bar{A}_{j} \cap\left(A_{i} \cap B_{i}\right)\right]
\end{align}

I'm not sure whether going from the first line to the second line is due to $E_i = \bigcap_{j=1}^{i-1} \overline{E_j}\cap E_i$ being generally true or it's only specifically true to this case, I tried but proving the general case but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, we have

$$X_i := \bigcap_{j=1}^{i-1} (\overline{E_j} \cap E_i) = \left( \bigcap_{j=1}^{i-1} \overline{E_j} \right) \cap E_i = \overline{\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1} E_j} \cap E_i = E_i \setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1} E_j,$$

which is always a subset of $E_i$, but not always equal to $E_i$. For example, if $E_i = \{1, \dots, i\}$ for all $i$, then $X_i = \{i\}$ for all $i$.

---

What is true is that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n X_i = \bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i$. This is pretty straightforward to prove by double containment: first, since $X_i \subseteq E_i$ for all $i$, we have $\bigcup_{i=1}^n X_i \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i$. For the other containment, let $a \in \bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i$ be arbitrary. Then define $k := \min \{i \in \{1, \dots, n\} : a \in E_i\}$ (this is well defined because $a$ is in at least one of the sets $E_i$). Now by definition, for all $j < k$ we have $a \notin E_j$. Thus, $a \notin \bigcup_{j=1}^{k-1} E_j$. Since also $a \in E_k$ we conclude that $a \in E_k \setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^{k-1} E_j = X_k$. Thus, $a \in \bigcup_{i=1}^n X_i$, as desired. $\square$